# Qt setting up new window

Tags: c++, forms, qt, user-interface

I have tried and tried to make a new window for my application. I got it to work and open the window but then when i tried to add my form .ui thing it just stoped working. Im sorry that i dont know what im doing wrong. Just someone please take a look at the code and help.

```
    #include "new_round.h"
    #include "ui_NewRound.h"

    New_Round::New_Round(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        uinr(new Uinr::New_Round)
    {   
uinr->setupUi(this);
    }
    New_Round::~New_Round()
    {
        delete uinr;
    }
```

That was the cpp file for the new_round class now here is the header.

```
    #ifndef NEW_ROUND_H
    #define NEW_ROUND_H

    #include "new_round.h"
    #include <QMainWindow>

    namespace Uinr{
     class New_Round;
    }

    class New_Round : public QMainWindow
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit New_Round(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~New_Round();

    private:
        Uinr::New_Round *uinr;
    };



    #endif // NEW_ROUND_H
```

and here are the 4 error i get

```
invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Uinr::New_Round'
forward declaration of 'struct Uinr::New_Round'
invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Uinr::New_Round'
forward declaration of 'struct Uinr::New_Round'
```

I coulnt find any tutorials on this subject so i kind of just looked back and forth between my mainwindow.h and mainwindow.cpp so in not sure what i did wrong. Again i did get the window to display but the formes NewRound.ui isnt working. Help!!

Answer (score 0):

Your header file `#include`s itself.  Take out that `#include` and replace it with `#include ui_Newound.h` and it should work.  You may need to run qmake and clean the project first, and possibly manually delete the Makefile.

Comment: It didnt work i changed the include and ran qmake, cleaned the project and the deleted the make files and restarted Qt but it still didnt work.

Comment: @user1438702 How did you add the form?  Through the QtCreator menu option, or manually?

Comment: through File->New File or Project->qt->New designer form

Comment: @user1438702 Try deleting the `ui_...` files, and re-running qmake etc.  FWIW I've had this exact problem and enough deleting and moving around `#include`s eventually solved it.  Note you do not need to restart QtCreator, save yourself the time.

Comment: i did it. i had the form dedigner add a .ui .cpp and .h automaticly. it came all set up

Comment: @user1438702 I'm saying delete them *now*, they may need to be updated to reflect the changed `#include`s--is that what you did?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, you need to define new_round as follows but, you don't want to include the header file itself. Also, you want to declare a pointer of type Ui_NewRound, not of type New_Round itself -- I assume you used the Designer to create this code in which case you end up with a class called Ui_NewRound. Also, don't bother with the namespace to begin with, it just makes things overly complicated. So here we go with the header file:

```
#ifndef NEW_ROUND_H
#define NEW_ROUND_H


#include <QMainWindow>
#include "Ui_NewRound.h"

// no including of new_round here -- this needs to be included in .cpp file instead
class New_Round : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    New_Round(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~New_Round();

private:
   Ui_NewRound *nr;


};

#endif
```

which will be saved as new_round.h.

In the .cpp code, I would then have

```
#include "new_round.h"
#include "ui_NewRound.h"


New_Round::New_Round(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{   
    nr = new ui_NewRound;
    nr->setupUi(this);
}
New_Round::~New_Round()
{
    delete nr;
}
```

Hope that gets you started!

Cheers,

Ben.

Comment: It gives me the errors:ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Ui_NewRound' with no type

Comment: Right, in that case you actually need to create a class of Ui_NewRound -- this is typically done using the Qt designer software. Or you can manually create it by hand!

Comment: ah i did it i had qt form designer add a .ui .cpp and .h all at once. it automaticly did it.